# OpenLayers plugin fails to install

Tags: openlayers-2

When I try to install OpenLayers plugin for QGIS 2.2.0 Valmiera I get the error message
the plugin is broken; python said: 
'QPyNULLVARIANT'object has no attribute '_*getitem*'

Does anyone have any ideas; i am a complete beginner, so I hope for a simple fix.
Or, where else can I get base maps.
I am using mac OS X 10.9.2

Thanks.

Comment: I have same problem here, maybe a dependence is not satisfaced?